# An error in my query

Tags: php, sql

I have a little problem with that :

```
public function is_present($Idarticle,$email){

$query=" SELECT * FROM envmail WHERE mail_env='$email' AND id_article='$Idarticle' ";

return mysql_query($query,$this->connection);

}

if($alert->is_present($idarticle,$email)){
echo "yes";
}
else echo "no";
```

mail_env is a varchar and id_article an int.
I have always yes .

Comment: `mysql_query` returns a resultset, which may or may not be an empty resultset, but is still a resultset.... you need to check the ___count___ of that resultset, if 0 then "no" else "yes".... Quoted from the manual: `Use mysql_num_rows() to find out how many rows were returned for a SELECT statement `

Comment: mysql_query returns TRUE on successful execution whether result empty or not.

Comment: my problem is I have always yes

Comment: it will only return false if `mysql_query` fails.

Comment: if I count i have always no
and if try if($alert->is_present($idarticle,$email)==TRUE) but no changement

Comment: Possible duplicate of the "return values" section of the official documentation http://nl3.php.net/mysql_query

Comment: So are you using `mysql_num_rows()`?

Comment: http://www.php.net/mysql_query please read *Return Values* section

Comment: with mysql_num_rows my code works thank you !
but I will search more why doesn't work without that :p thx all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this.

```
public function is_present($Idarticle,$email){

$query=" SELECT * FROM envmail WHERE mail_env='$email' AND id_article='$Idarticle' ";

$result = mysql_query($query,$this->connection);

//return mysql_num_rows($result);
// Update as suggested by @Mark
return mysql_num_rows($result) !== 0

}


//if($alert->is_present($idarticle,$email) > 0 ){
// Updated
if($alert->is_present($idarticle,$email)){
echo "yes";
}
else echo "no";
```

Comment: `return mysql_num_rows($result) !== 0;` will return a nice boolean

Answer (score 0):

```
public function is_present($Idarticle,$email){

$query=" SELECT * FROM envmail WHERE mail_env='".$email."' AND id_article='".$Idarticle."' ";

$result = mysql_query($query,$this->connection);

return mysql_num_rows($result);

}


if($alert->is_present($idarticle,$email) > 0 ){
echo "yes";
}
else echo "no";
```